# Show nested datatable without repeating original data

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I want to show the data from the database but can not repeat the same profile, just add a location to the existing profile. With the example above becomes clear:

```
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   PROFILE         |   LOCATION    |   STATUS      |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Admin           |   Chief       |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Director        |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Secretary       |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Admin       |   OK          |
|                   |   Chief       |   OK          |
|   Chief-accessor  |   Director    |   OK          |
|                   |   Secretary   |   OK          |
|                   |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

With this piece of code that is my datatable, I can only repeat them, but I can not group them:

```
<rich:panel header="User location info" style="margin: 20px 0 !important;">
    <h:dataTable id="userLocationList"
        value="#{userLocation.list()}" var="row"
        styleClass="rich-table"
        headerClass="rich-table-subheader rich-table-subheadercell rich-table-thead"
        rowClasses="rich-table-row"
        columnClasses="rich-table-cell,rich-table-cell,rich-table-cell">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Profile" />
            </f:facet>
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.profile}" />
            </center>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Location" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{row.location}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Status" />
            </f:facet>
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.profile.status ? 'OK' : 'Inactive'}" />
            </center>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</rich:panel>
```

Like this:

```
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   PROFILE         |   LOCATION    |   STATUS      |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Admin           |   Chief       |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Director        |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Secretary       |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Chief-accessor  |   Admin       |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Chief-accessor  |   Chief       |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Chief-accessor  |   Director    |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Chief-accessor  |   Secretary   |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   Chief-accessor  |   Supervision |   OK          |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Method `list()` from `UserLocation` is just a `select` in `table_user_location`:

`select userLoc from UserLocation userLoc where userLoc.user.id = :userId`

I've tried to follow some answers here in StackOverflow that say to put a datatable inside another datatable, but as I could was to repeat all locations without group profiles, example:

```
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|   PROFILE         |   LOCATION    |   STATUS      |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Chief       |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Admin       |               |
|   Admin           |   Chief       |   OK          |
|                   |   Director    |               |
|                   |   Secretary   |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Chief       |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Admin       |               |
|   Director        |   Chief       |   OK          |
|                   |   Director    |               |
|                   |   Secretary   |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Chief       |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Admin       |               |
|   Secretary       |   Chief       |   OK          |
|                   |   Director    |               |
|                   |   Secretary   |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Chief       |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Admin       |               |
|   Chief-accessor  |   Chief       |   OK          |
|                   |   Director    |               |
|                   |   Secretary   |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
|                   |   Chief       |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
|                   |   Admin       |               |
|   Chief-accessor  |   Chief       |   OK          |
|                   |   Director    |               |
|                   |   Secretary   |               |
|                   |   Supervision |               |
+-------------------+---------------+---------------+
And so it goes...
```

My doubt is the generic query I'm doing, so the duplicate content in the table. Does anyone have an idea for this operation?

Questions related:

- [Nested datatable in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7493595/939803)
- [JSF: Empty nested dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9776773/939803)
- [JSF, datatable in datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1062565/939803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was not able to do it the way they return all locations for the same profile and using only one query, I decided to do differently, I thought of using two queries, one for all without repetition profiles (`select distinct ...`) and one for each location according to the profile. Only realized (correct me if I'm wrong) the property `h:datatable` renders by columns rather than rows. So, in part, was the first profile column returned all without repeating profiles, however the locations were the same in each cell was shown all user locations without distinction if the cell that the location would appear was of a given profile. That's when I realized I was very focused in locations where the focus was to be on user profiles.

Ran the `select distinct` the profiles and created a method to return the locations that profiles at the time the table was created. Just as the reported questions, a `datatable` inside another `datatable`.

Finally got my code:

```
<rich:panel header="Informations" style="margin: 20px 0 !important;">
    <h:dataTable id="userLocationList"
        value="#{userLocation.list()}" var="row"
        styleClass="rich-table"
        headerClass="rich-table-subheader rich-table-subheadercell rich-table-thead"
        rowClasses="rich-table-row"
        columnClasses="rich-table-cell,rich-table-cell,rich-table-cell">
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Profile" />
            </f:facet>
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />
            </center>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Localizations" />
            </f:facet>
                <h:dataTable id="uLoc" var="c" 
                value="#{home.getLocByProfile(row.idProfile)}">
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{c}" />
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Status" />
            </f:facet>
            <center>
                <h:outputText value="#{row.active ? 'OK' : 'Inactive'}" />
            </center>
        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
</rich:panel>
```